# Barycentric coordinates.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Let a,b,c$\ne0$. Show that the set of all points whose barycentric coordinates λ,μ,ν that satisfy aλ+bμ+cν=0 is a line

L is line in the plane iff
L=p+[v] where v is direction vector
If we have three non colliner points
Abd if lemda and mew and ve are the bary centric corrdinat of points in plane , prove that if lemda *a+mew*b+ve*c=0 wherea,b,c real not all zero prove it forms line

Comment: Post searchable text... not unsearchable image.

Comment: Please read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a good question. Please make sure your question is very roughly 350 to 600 characters with context and your tries to solve it. Others:p please be nice to newbies.

Comment: About barycentric coordinates in general, a well written document [here](https://koblbauermath.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/1/9/13192946/barycentric_coordinates.pdf)

Comment: Besides, please show your work.

Comment: @mjw note the “very roughly”

Comment: @mjw this is irrelevant you know what I mean, right$^?$.

Comment: right!${}{}{}{}{}$